# SELECT doesn't return value on "AND"

Tags: mysql, sql

Am I missing something? My table contains:

- `country` with the value '`usa`'
- `school-type` with the value '`4 Year University`'

If I use row 2, the query returns '220'. If I use row 4, it also returns '220'. If I use both with 'OR' between them, it returns '220' twice, but if I use 'AND', it doesn't return anything. Any ideas?

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE
(   (meta_key='school-type' AND meta_value='Community College')
 OR (meta_key='school-type' AND meta_value='4 Year University'))
AND
(   (meta_key='country' AND meta_value='usa')
 OR (meta_key='country' AND meta_value='canada'))
```

Comment: can you provide your database schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` filters each row, so it is not possible for `meta_key` to be school-type and country.

Try a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE meta_key='school-type' OR meta_key='country'
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING SUM(
    IF(meta_key='school-type',
      meta_value='Community College' OR meta_value='4 Year University',
      meta_value='usa' OR meta_value='canada'
      )) = 2
```

Or, If you want to get both rows:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE
((meta_key='school-type' AND meta_value='Community College') OR (meta_key='school-type' AND meta_value='4 Year University'))
OR
((meta_key='country' AND meta_value='usa') OR (meta_key='country' AND meta_value='canada'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, a single row can't have a `meta_key` of both "school-type" and "country". Combining the two different searches results in 0 results because of this.

Answer (score 0):

you query is wrong . 
Let's take example 
if meta_key='school-type'
than it can't be country so your second condition will always return fast.